# regexp does not identify only filenames but even characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm using a regexp to see if the string contains a filename such as P1190681 or not. The problem is that the regexp thinks that the letters in a string is the filename or something like that. Let me show you what I mean.

Here's my regexp which will identify the filename (for example P1190681 or PICT1136): `([P|PICT0-9_{,7}]+)`. If the string (for example "Entered correct CAPTCHA") contains any P, I, C, T, or any numbers it will turn these to links, which is **wrong**!

How can I make this regexp to **only** identify filenames as those I used as examples?

Comment: Alternatives go in `(this|or|that)` parenthesis. And square brackets `[..]` are for character lists `[0-9]`. You are confusing those.

Comment: Ah! I'm still new to regexp :) Many thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mario, here's the solution: `(P[0-9]|PICT[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Your answer `(P[0-9]|PICT[0-9]+)` would only allow one digit after `P`

To match `P1190681` or `PICT1136` you could use, for example

```
P(ICT)?[0-9]+
```